# React Native render error Value is undefined expected a object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-reanimated

So  I dont know why I am getting this weird error and I am unable to find any solution for it so plz help with me

**Error**
[image]

[image]

**Code**

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
  2 import Animated, { Easing, useAnimatedProps } from 'react-native-reanimated'
  3 import { Path, PathProps } from 'react-native-svg'
  4
  5 interface AnimatedStrokeProps extends PathProps {
  6   progress: Animated.SharedValue<number>
  7 }
  8
  9 const AnimatedPath = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Path)
 10
 11 const AnimatedStroke = ({ progress, ...pathProps }: AnimatedStrokeProps) => {
 12   const [length, setLength] = useState(0)
 13   const ref = useRef<typeof AnimatedPath>(null)
 14   const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => ({
 15     strokeDashoffset: Math.max(
 16       0,
 17       length - length * Easing.bezier(0.37, 0, 0.63, 1)(progress.value) - 0.1
 18     )
 19   }))
 20
 21   return (
 22     <AnimatedPath
 23       animatedProps={animatedProps}
 24       // @ts-ignore
 25       onLayout={() => setLength(ref.current!.getTotalLength())}
 26       // @ts-ignore
 27       ref={ref}
 28       strokeDasharray={length}
 29       {...pathProps}
 30     />
 31   )
 32 }
 33
 34 export default AnimatedStroke
```

So plz help me out i rlly rlly need help in it.

Answer (score 0):

Update your react-native-reanimated version.In my case I have react-native-reanimated version 2.3.1 and rolling back to 2.2.4 version.After that I occurred that error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).